# Notification snoozes alarm?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, email, notifications, alarm, k9-mail

Found a pretty interesting feature/bug from the combination of K-9 Mail and the stock Alarm app on my Galaxy S (rooted + Darky's Rom 10.2, 2.3.4). This morning, just as the alarm started to ring, I got an email. This caused the alarm to snooze and the short email notification sound I have to play. I'd think that an alarm would have preference over an email notification, and thankfully I had a regular alarm clock as a backup.

Has anybody else run into this problem or is it just me? Suggestions how to avoid in the future?

Answer (score 1):

As long as the alarm in fact snoozed and didn't get turned off I'd think you'd be safe, just maybe a bit later than normal. :) I can't find any other info about how to force alarms to play over notifications or of anyone  else having the issue. If you're worried you could silence your phone at night, then notifications would be silent but the alarm would still go off.